# PySpark: How can I import a GitHub library into Databricks?

Tags: github, import, pyspark, installation, databricks

I would like to use this library for anomaly detection in Databricks: [iForest](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest) .This library can not be installed through PyPi.

How can I install libraries from GitHub in Databricks? I read about using something called an "egg" but I don't quite understand how it should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone the repo and create a Python package as explained here : https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest:

> Step 2. Package pyspark-iforest and install it via pip, skip this
> step if you don't need the python pkg
>
> `cd spark-iforest/python`
>
> `python setup.py sdist`
>
> `pip install dist/pyspark-iforest-<version>.tar.gz`

Here you only need the 2 first commands to generate the package but you have to change the second one to generate an egg package instead of source distribution package:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_egg
```

Now, you'll find the file in `/dist` folder:

```
pyspark_iforest-2.4.0-py3.7.egg
```

Finally, on Databricks, select **Create > Library** and choose **Python Egg** to upload the generated file. More details can be found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html#create-a-workspace-library).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use %pip to install notebook-scoped libraries (see [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html#manage-libraries-with-pip-commands)) from GitHub.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Try to elaborate how can that solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a location mounted on Databricks you can also copy the `pyspark-iforest-<version>.tar.gz` file there and `pip install` from there. Or use the upload functionality if it's enabled, see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#upload-data-to-dbfs-from-the-file-browser).

Comment: Instead of just providing link can you explain what should be done in your words? In future these links can get broken or move to another location

Answer (score 0):

```
%sh git clone https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest
```

Then make sure it is cloned in the `databricks` driver root path

```
%sh ls -al
```

And then  `pip install` if desired using:

```
%pip install ./{yourpackage_name}
```

If it returns message that the requirement is already satisfied, you have to do:

```
 %pip uninstall -y {yourpackage_name}
```

This would remove any version of the libraries that may have installed from `PyPi` instead of the git clone version. Next, redo the pip install package in databricks.